# Removing indexed data using android app indexing(Do not show indexed data in google search results)

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

I am able to display the indexed content on default google search results(auto complete) by using "AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(mGoogleApiClient, indexAction);"

but after that I decided to remove the some of the indexed content from google search results(auto complete).

For Example:
In first version of the app indexed below content.
1. Dummy content(android-app://com.myindexingapp/sample/Dummy content)
2. Dummy content2(android-app://com.myindexingapp/sample/Dummy content2)

I am able to see both Dummy content and Dummy content2 in google search result on my device.

In second version I want to show only Dummy content
means I want to un index Dummy content2(android-app://com.myindexingapp/sample/Dummy content2)

Can any one help me how can we achieve this?

I tried using "AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(mGoogleApiClient, indexAction);"
with same action but it is not working.

Here I use "GoogleApiClient" and "AppIndex.AppIndexApi" to index data(didn't used latest firebase indexing in first version).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this using below code.

```
com.google.firebase.appindexing.Action fbIndexAction = Actions.newView(title, BASE_APP_URI.toString());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "@@@@ data path here " + title + " uri here " + BASE_APP_URI);
            FirebaseUserActions.getInstance().end(fbIndexAction);

            FirebaseAppIndex.getInstance().remove(BASE_APP_URI.toString());
```